# How to display Duration depending on it's value

Tags: flutter, dart, duration

For example i have some of the following `Duration` values

```
0:12:15.000000 // the hour is 0 so i want to display the value like mm-ss => 12:15
0:01:02.000000 // the minutes is less than 10 so i want to display the value like m-ss => 1:02
0:00:05.000000  // the minutes is 0 so i want to the value like m-ss => 0:05
```

i import these Duration values from video info so i don't know what was the type of `.000000` is . but i want to remove them too .

How could i handle these scenarios in best way :)

Comment: you have https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration/inMinutes.html property so you can use it in `if` statement to choose the desired display format

Comment: thanks , but i can't understand how does inMinutes property solving my issue . it is only calculated the whole value in Minutes

Comment: if (minutes > 60) format = 'hh:mm:ss' else if (minutes > 1) format = 'mm:ss' else format = 'ss'

Comment: alright i get you now . But How can i get format value ? ok if (minutes > 60) 1 h ? 2 h ? 3 .. etc ?

Comment: here you have format values: https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html - i was wrong as 'hh' or 'mm' are not correct formats - the docs say: "DateFormat is for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner.

It allows the user to choose from a set of standard date time formats as well as specify a customized pattern under certain locales."

Comment: the problem is that .format() does not accept Duration . if it accept so my issue solved , any suggestion ?

Comment: read `DateTime` official documentation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have duration object. You can define your format function something like this and use it.

```
  String _formatVideoDuration(Duration duration) {
    final hours = (duration.inHours);
    final minutes = (duration.inMinutes % 60);
    final ss = (duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    if (hours > 9) {
      return '${hours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:$ss';
    } else if (hours > 0) {
      return '${hours.toString().padLeft(1, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:$ss';
    } else if (minutes > 9) {
      return '${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:$ss';
    } else {
      return '${minutes.toString().padLeft(1, '0')}:$ss';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might help

```
String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
  String twoDigitMinutes = duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  String twoDigitSeconds = duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  
  if (duration.inHours == 0) {
    return '$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds';
  } else if (duration.inMinutes < 10) {
    return '${duration.inHours}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds';
  } else {
    return '${duration.inHours}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds';
  }
}

Duration duration = Duration(hours: 0, minutes: 12, seconds: 15);
String formattedDuration = formatDuration(duration);
print(formattedDuration); // prints "12:15"

duration = Duration(hours: 0, minutes: 1, seconds: 2);
formattedDuration = formatDuration(duration);
print(formattedDuration); // prints "1:02"

duration = Duration(hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 5);
formattedDuration = formatDuration(duration);
print(formattedDuration); // prints "0:05"
```